# Java PreparedStatement error

Tags: java, sql

I've got the following code. It attempts to basically handle data submitted from jsf form then insert the data into the table in the database. Now the database we have installed is quite old...it is sql server 2000 so I used jtds as driver. the code:

```
 public void dbConnect(String db_connect_string,
            String db_userid,
            String db_password)
    {
      try {
         Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string,
                  db_userid, db_password);
         System.out.println("connected");
         dateSubmitted = "dasdasd";
         /*HERE THE STATEMENTS TO INSERT*/
         java.sql.PreparedStatement insertData = null;
         String insertStatement = "INSERT INTO SLMDATA VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,"
                 + "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
         insertData = conn.prepareStatement(insertStatement);
         insertData.setString(1, serviceLogger); 
         insertData.setString(2, dateSubmitted);
         insertData.setString(3, serviceName);
         insertData.setString(4, department);
         insertData.setString(5, division);
         insertData.setString(6, businessServiceDescription );
         insertData.setString(7, technicalServiceDescription);
         insertData.setString(8, serviceCustomer);
         insertData.setString(9, serviceCriticality);
         insertData.setString(10, serviceRequestSystem);
         insertData.setString(11, serviceCategory);
         insertData.setString(12, serviceHours );
         insertData.setString(13, availabilityTarget);
         insertData.setString(14, lowIncidentResponseScale );
         insertData.setString(15, lowIncidentResponseHrsType );
         insertData.setString(16, lowResponseTimeText);
         insertData.setString(17, mediumIncidentResponseScale);
         insertData.setString(18, mediumIncidentResponseHrsType);
         insertData.setString(19, mediumResponseTimeText);
         insertData.setString(20, highIncidentResponseScale);
         insertData.setString(21, highIncidentResponseHrsType );
         insertData.setString(22, highResponseTimeText );
         insertData.setString(23, lowIncidentResolutionScale );
         insertData.setString(24, lowIncidentResolutionHrsType );
         insertData.setString(25, lowResolutionTimeText );
         insertData.setString(26, mediumIncidentResolutionScale );
         insertData.setString(27, mediumIncidentResolutionHrsType );
         insertData.setString(28, mediumResolutionTimeText );
         insertData.setString(29, highIncidentResolutionScale );
         insertData.setString(30, highIncidentResolutionHrsType);
         insertData.setString(31, highResolutionTimeText );
         insertData.setString(32, blockTime );
         insertData.setString(33, impactedServices);
         insertData.setString(34, operationalDependencies );
         insertData.setString(35, disasterAvailable );
         insertData.setString(36, configurationItems );
         insertData.executeUpdate();

         conn.close();
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("thankyou.xhtml");

      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }


    public void callConnection(){

        dbConnect("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host;", "username",
                   "password");
    }
```

and the glassfish server console output shows:

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'SLMDATA'.

SLMDATA is the name of table and am sure it is correct. When i step through the code via the breakpoint feature, I reach until executeQuery, then things get out of control. I've looked into the content of all variables, and all are valid. Any idea what is going on? been stuck on this for a while

Comment: Possible duplicates: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909599/java-mssql-java-sql-sqlexception-invalid-object-name-tablename) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647846/invalid-object-name) - You could try a simple `SELECT * FROM SLMDATA` to see if you get the same error.

Comment: Thanks that did it @assylias :D really appreciate it and sorry for overlooking that one :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try to put the schema name before the table schemaName.table or create a synonym in your DB for the schema.